# VC post-build event command

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Now I am building a .dll project with VC 10. Depending on whether certain libraries are included or not, the output .dll as well as its corresponding lib file names should be different. For example, if the project uses the native STL library provided by Mirosoft, the .dll name is *_native_stl.dll; if the project uses STLport, then the output .dll name is *_stlport.dll. Of course I can do it manually, but I am now considering to let VC 10 do it for me automatically. My plan is that if I use a certain library, I define a variable to represent it in the **Preprocessor Definitions** (located in C/C++ Preprocessor)section. After that, I define a .bat file in the **Post-Build Event** (located in Build Events) section: `call "$(ProjectDir)\script.bat"`. In the script.bat file, I will changed the default .dll output name `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)` according to the variable definition in the **Preprocessor Definitions** section. My main problem is that for in batch file how I can check a certain variable is defined or not. Thanks! Any suggestions on changing output file name are welcome as well.

Comment: Why don't you use different build configurations, with per-configuration settings for output names, definitions etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I do not know where I can find the per-configuration settings in VC 10. Could you give me a clue?

Comment: [Build Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa%28v=vs.100%29) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

```
My main problem is that for in batch file how I can check a certain variable is defined or not. Thanks!
```

You can check this with a statement like this:

```
if "%MYVAR%" == "" set undefined=1
```

The variable *undefined* will be set to 1 only if *MYVAR* is not defined.